# What could be causing a steady tapping noise in a tankless water heater?

Tags: plumbing

I have a Jacuzzi hot water heater, installed about 2 years ago. It works fine, however, when it is sitting idle (no making hot water) it has recently developed a steady tapping noise from within. When I shut off the incoming or outgoing water valves it stops.
I opened up the cover and blow out any dirt with compressed air. I cleaned the water filter. 
Any ideas?

Comment: I am guessing it is electric since you blow it out. Could there be air in the tank and that is causing the noise. A model number would be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure the click is inside the heater? Thermal expansion of pipes will sometimes cause a similar sound.

Comment: Does this tapping happen only after recent usage?

Answer (score 1):

An experienced plumber explained that the tapping noise could be gas trapped under sediment at the bottom of the tank. As the gas rises the bubble "explodes", creating a tapping noise. Draining the tank could remove some of the sediment, but the best thing is to call a professional for help.